# Apache POI update excell Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to update a .xlsx file in java using Apache POI.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class updateResults {


   void updateResults(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow row1 = sheet.getRow(1);
    XSSFCell cell1 = row1.getCell(1);
    cell1.setCellValue("Mahesh");
    XSSFRow row2 = sheet.getRow(2);
    XSSFCell cell2 = row2.getCell(1);
    cell2.setCellValue("Ramesh");
    fis.close();
    FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
    workbook.write(fos);
    fos.close();
    System.out.println("Done");

 } 
 }
```

The problem is i get a null pointer exception at line "32" which is `XSSFCell cell2 = row2.getCell(1);`

Anybody ahve any idea why is this happening?

Comment: How many rows has your sheet?

Comment: Put it in a loop with the limit as the number of rows you are expecting and do null checks for rows and cell before calling getCell or getValue respectively.

Comment: Thank you :) most helpful question ever :) @Jens

Comment: The exception implies you do not have row 2.That's why it returning null so nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException` is thrown when an application attempts to use an object reference, having the `null` value. These include: Calling an instance method on the object referred by a `null reference`.
May be you do not have value in your row 2 so nullpointerexception.

Comment: Thank you. I have another problem now. If i change width or height of cells or rows manualy through excell and then try to send updates i get exception "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: New Problem... New Question dear... :)